# 2.8: Turning on normals on both sides

Tags: normals

In Unreal Engine, the roof(this is a plane) of a house object created by Blender is transparent from inside.

[image]

I guess that it is necessary to recalculate inside normals.

[image]

However, if I do that I will lose the outside normals and the roof is transparent from outside, I think.

[image]

So how can I resolve this problem? Shouldn't I use a plane for the roof?

Comment: you need to give it thickness, to do so, just extrude

Comment: Check the box that says " 2 sided" in the material properties in Unreal Engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your different solutions, I confirmed that both worked!